# Untar file with subprocess.call is running successfully but with no effect

Tags: python, extract, tar

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong with this command:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('tar -zvxf %s -C %s' % ("file.tar.gz", '/folder'), shell=True)
```

The code runs without any errors but the file is only unzipped on random occasions. I know I can use `tarfile`, but I would like to run it as a Linux command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the man page, you'll see that the `-C` parameter is sensitive to order -- it only affects operations that come after it on the command line.  So, your file is being unzipped into whatever random directory you happen to be in.

You don't need shell for this.  Do:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir('/folder')
subprocess.call( ['tar','xvfz', 'file.tar.gz'] )
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. It works. One thing about my question I still do not understand is why the command sometimes takes a few minutes to execute (as it should) and why it sometimes runs for a few milliseconds?

Comment: I can't tell you that.  Are you fetching this file from a web site?  Perhaps it isn't completely fetched by the time you unpack it.